# Ant - multiple conditions to drive a property value

Tags: ant, properties, conditional-statements, multiple-conditions

I am trying to add multiple AND conditions in a Ant check target to set a property. I want to perform certain action based on the property being set.

```
<target name="checkVal">
    <condition property="val.present">
        <and>
            <available file="${srcDir}/somefile"/>
            <matches pattern="MyClass.java" string="${pathString}"/>
        </and>
    </condition>
    <fail message="Failing the condition."/>
</target>

<target name="doSomething" depends="checkVal" if="val.present">
    ...
</target>
```

The intention is to execute "doSomething" if the property `val.present` is set by the 2 conditions within the `<and>` block. One condition checks whether a file is available, and another checks whether a path string contains a particular source file.

I am getting the fail message always.

The following works though:

```
<target name="checkVal">
    <available file="${srcDir}/somefile" property="val.present"/>
</target>

<target name="doSomething" depends="checkVal" if="val.present">
    ...
</target>
```

Could someone tell me how I can get this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked after I replaced the `matches` task with a `contains` task.

```
<target name="checkVal">
    <condition property="val.present">
        <and>
            <available file="${srcDir}/somefile"/>
            <contains substring="MyClass.java" string="${srcDir}"/>
        </and>
    </condition>    
</target>
```